# Is interface required on a class extending an abstract class already implementing the interface?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

Assume there is a code as such:

```
package com.ps.Sample;

public interface Sample
{
    public void Method1();
}

public abstract class AbstractSample implements Sample
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

public class MySample extends AbstractSample
{

}

public class TestSample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Sample my = new MySample();

        my.Method1();
    }

}
```

My question is:
  Is there any benefit to declaring the concrete class as

```
public class MySample extends AbstractSample implements Sample
```

instead of

```
public class MySample extends AbstractSample
```

Comment: Note: the abstract class implements the interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not. It's redundant. AbstractSample *is a* Sample, and MySample *is a* AbstractSample. So MySample *is a* Sample.

The javadoc displays all the implemented interfaces anyway, whether you add the `implements Sample` or not.

Comment: Try to explain it using Person class like, something like.. we don't need to say that Teacher is Walker because Teacher is Person and Person is alredy Walker. IMO using Sample to explain it could not show the redundancy at all.

Comment: You just did it :-) I used the same class names as the OP.

Answer (score 4):

One benefit would be that if AbstractSample was changed to not implement Sample, the first declaration would still allow you to pass instances of MySample to methods expecting a Sample.